# Facebook SDK 4.0 get additional permissions

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, permissions

In my app i want to ask permissions to log-in the user and for `publish_actions`.
I want to publish a picture on the user wall after he does a certain action but when i ask for publish permissions the request get cancelled.
I am using `logInWithPublishPermissions` to get needed permissions.
I also tried with

```
mAuthBtn.cancelPermission()
```

but nothing changed.
I am looking for a way to obtain both permissions, even if not together.

Comment: What do you mean by "the request get cancelled"?

Comment: the `onCancel` method of `FacebookCallback` gets called

Comment: which permission u are using for posing photo

Comment: I need the publish_actions permission. actually i am not posting anything since i don't have permissions

Answer (score -1):

```
    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile,user_birthday,email"));
```

as you can see in the above example i am asking for birthday email and public profile. you can do the same for the permission you need.

**Since you want to post your app must be reviewed by facebook to allow you to post**

Comment: No because you cannot ask for `public_profile` and `public_actions` together.

Comment: who told that public_actions and email are given by default,  you dont have to ask also,show your code maybe i can help you out.